# Can you have "ferromagnetic" order that preserves time-reversal symmetry?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking, time-reversal-symmetry, spin-models, ferromagnetism

Usually in systems with ferromagnetic order, the spin $\mathrm{O}(3) = \mathrm{SO}(3) \times Z_2^t$ (where $Z_2^t$ represents time-reversal) symmetry is broken down to $\mathrm{SO}(2)$. Is it possible to have a spontaneous symmetry breaking phase where the residual symmetry group is $\mathrm{SO}(2) \times Z_2^t$ instead, that is, time-reversal symmetry is preserved? Is there a name for such a phase?

Note: I am *not* referring to spin-nematic order. In that case, the residual symmetry is $(\mathrm{SO}(2) \rtimes Z_2) \times Z_2^t$.

Comment: There is a trivial answer where the constituent particles are themselves time-reversal invariant. This is a ferroelectric (alignment of electric dipoles) I guess. I think it's impossible to create what you want out of spins, since the action of time-reversal is exactly the same as the action of flipping magnetization. It's probably not too hard to prove using that fact.